# Define C-like multiline comment

Tags: comments

I am aware of other comment options, but I want to define /* as opening for mulitiline comment and */ as closing.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is so far from standard tex syntax that any solution is going to be very fragile and only work if the document obeys lots of extra conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might break other things (David points out that the braces in a comment must be balanced, for example and you can't have a `%` preceding the closing `*/` on the same line; also, other uses of `/` inside an argument will be trashed, for example a slash as part of an `\includegraphics` subdirectory filename).

This approach makes `/` active, which means it is now a macro name, and will absorb space after it, so if you use a `/` by itself, you may need to add `{}` following it, so that subsequent (desired) space is not suppressed.

I concur with David's strong recommendation **NOT** to use this approach, because of the gotchas!

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svslash/
\catcode`/=\active
\makeatletter
\def/{\@ifnextchar*{\ccomment}{\svslash}}
\makeatother
\long\def\ccomment*#1*/{}
\begin{document}
Here is/* a comment that I want
to go on

and on

and on*/ something that I am testing.  But a normal /{} passes through.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but you can't comment out `}` or a `%` on the last line or .....

Comment: `\includegraphics{images/hmm}` might be interesting as well. (note these are not criticsms of your answer, just trying to persuade the OP not to use this syntax:-)

Answer (score 1):

One can setup a parser with `pgf`'s `parser` module such that it gobbles any token, the only problem is we have to make `/` active, so it can't be used in filenames, Ti*k*Z or pgf options, etc.

Also it changes the catcode of `%` locally, such that they can appear inside of a C-comment, though this will fail if the input in already tokenized (so if it is already part of a macro).

## Don't use this!

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\pgfparserdef{ccomment}{initial}*{\pgfparserswitch{star}}
\pgfparserdefunknown{ccomment}{star}{\pgfparserswitch{initial}}
\pgfparserdeffinal{ccomment}{\endgroup}
% we have to put this here, as the `/` would otherwise not work in the options
\pgfparserset{ccomment/silent=true}
\let\svslash/
\catcode`\/=\active
\makeatletter
\def/{\@ifnextchar*{\@firstoftwo\ccomment}{\svslash}}
\makeatother
\pgfparserdef{ccomment}{star}/{\pgfparserswitch{final}}
\newcommand*\ccomment
  {%
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\%=12
    \catcode`\*=12 % just to make sure `*` has the correct meaning
    \pgfparserparse{ccomment}%
  }

\begin{document}
some /*comment that gobbles} %unbalanced{tokenlists*/ but a normal one /\ slips
through
\end{document}
```